# Is there a way to open an m3u8 playlist on android

Tags: video, streaming

I'm using Android 2.2. Trying to open an m3u8 playlist file directly from a http source. Dolphin browser just asks me to save the file.

Any ideas on how I can stream the content.... is there a market app for this?

Jason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without doing any research about it at all, this sounds like something that's right up [WinAmp](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.nullsoft.winamp&feature=search_result)'s alley.  I know it supports streaming audio, but streaming video might be a different matter.

**Edit:** Also, [this guy](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=8354560&postcount=4) suggests renaming .m3u8 files to .m3u as .m3u has wider support in apps.  Perhaps save the .m3u8 file you want from the web, rename the extension, and play it that way?

Answer (score 4):

M3U8 is the Unicode version of [M3U](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M3U), which is simply a playlist file, providing a media player a list of media files to play.  Open it up in a text editor & you'll see from the contents.

It's a very simple format & most media players will pick it up.  The default media player included in the Android OS uses M3U for its internal playlists.  More info [here](http://www.gomobi.org/tips/creat-music-playlists-for-android-mobile-phones.html).

I suspect that's not what you're asking though, since you mentioned streaming.  You don't "play" an M3U file, you play the content it refers to within.  Your best chance of success is to open the M3U[8] file on your PC and look at the actual video content URL(s) and try to load one directly in your media player of choice.  If that doesn't work, ask back here but provide the media URL so we can attempt to work out its format.

If you do find the underlying video stream format, [this handy reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html) lists the supported stream types.

Comment: Thanks, I basically wanted my android phone to open up the m3u8 file and play all the contents. If i find a link i'll post it. cheers.

Answer (score 0):

I think [VPlayer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=me.abitno.vplayer.t) can stream it for you. They have a free trial but after the trial it is like 4USD to unlock the full version.

Comment: How about a link?

Answer (score 0):

You can find "NX Streaming Player" on Playstore. It supports any URL that finishes with .m3u8  - for example:

http://www.domain.net/video/abc123/playlist.m3u8

There is a lot of apps like it, but I think this is the best to play one URL each time, manually inserting the address.

Answer (score 0):

its been 7 years passed since you posted. I believe you have got several options to do play m3u8. Even currently android builtin media player is able to play live urls inside an m3u8. Basically m3u8 is nothing else but text file  to android. So you have to make m3u parser. If you are just looking for application, you can try [and iptv](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amigo.ltv) which is free to use. However if you need help for development, bump to this answer so i can get back to you . I could already give you instruction but it will be like digging a grave!

Cheers

Comment: Link not found may be it is expired